# Android How to add a Gallery image into a Drawing App

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing

I am creating an app in which people can draw a sketch and save to the gallery. This I have done and is working fine. What I would like to be able to do is take an image from the Gallery and be able to draw on that. I have been able to bring up the Gallery to pick the image but I havent been able to work out how to imbed that image onto the canvas to then draw on

here is my code for the gallery button:

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.GalleryButton){
            //new button
            AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
            newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
            newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);


                }

            });
            newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            newDialog.show();
        }
```

I'm sure something must go after the `startActivityForResult` part and that is what I cant work out. Where I want to imbed the image is `(R.id.drawing)`.

EDIT:

Here is the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//custom drawing view
private DrawingView drawView;
//buttons
private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn, saveBtn, galleryBtn, cameraBtn;
//sizes
private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;

Bitmap bitmap;

protected static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get drawing view
    drawView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);

    //get the palette and first color button
    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
    currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

    //sizes from dimensions
    smallBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    mediumBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    largeBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.large_size);

    //draw button
    drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //set initial size
    drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);

    //erase button
    eraseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
    eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //new button
    newBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
    newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //save button
    saveBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //new button
    galleryBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.GalleryButton);
    galleryBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //new button
    cameraBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.camera_btn);
    cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//user clicked paint
public void paintClicked(View view){
    //use chosen color

    //set erase false
    drawView.setErase(false);
    drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

    if(view!=currPaint){
        ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
        String color = view.getTag().toString();
        drawView.setColor(color);
        //update ui
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
        currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    if(view.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
        //draw button clicked
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //listen for clicks on size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //show and wait for user interaction
        brushDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.erase_btn){
        //switch to erase - choose size
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Eraser size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        brushDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.new_btn){
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                drawView.startNew();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                //attempt to save
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
                //feedback
                if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    unsavedToast.show();
                }
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.show();
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.GalleryButton){
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 101);


            }

        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
    }

    else if(view.getId()==R.id.camera_btn){
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChoosePicture.class); 
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
}

@Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        InputStream stream = null;
                        if (requestCode == 101&& resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                // We need to recycle unused bitmaps
                                if (bitmap != null) 
                                {
                                    bitmap.recycle();
                                }
                                stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                imageView.getLayoutParams().height = bitmap.getHeight()/8;
                            }
                            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (stream != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    stream.close();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
}
```

CODE FOR RAGHUNANDAN:

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.GalleryButton){
            //new button
            AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
            newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
            newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void  setDrawingThemefrmGallery()
                {
                    // To open up a gallery browser
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
                    // To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the following to your Activity
                }

                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
                String s= getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
                File file = new File(s);

                if (file.exists()) {
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                drawView.setBackground(d);
                }
                else
                {
                       // file does not exist
                }

                }
                }
                }
                /**
                 * @param contentURI
                 * @return
                 */
                private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                        return contentURI.getPath();
                    } else { 
                        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
                        return cursor.getString(idx); 
                    }
                }
```

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

Also if the image is too large to fit in you may have to scale down before setting it as a background. Use appropriate `BitmapFactory.decode` method as needed.

```
public void  setDrawingThemefrmGallery()
{
    // To open up a gallery browser
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
    // To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the following to your Activity
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
String s= getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
File file = new File(s);

if (file.exists()) {
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
drawView.setBackground(d);
}
else
{
       // file does not exist
}

}
}
}
/**
 * @param contentURI
 * @return
 */
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}
```

Snap Shot

Image picked from gallery which is a background to your drawing view and you can draw on the same.

[image]

Comment: when I click on the button I have created in order to bring the gallery up its doesnt do anything.

Comment: I'll put the code up, if you could have a look for me that would be great.

Comment: @PaulH why are you use onActivityResultt inside a alert dialog its a overriden method of your activity class. also check the override annotation.

Comment: @PaulH check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) you are doing it wrong. override `onActivityResult` for your activity class not inside alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

Put a request code for **startActivityForResult**

```
startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 101);
```

Then add this to you code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == 101&& resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        try 
        {
            // We need to recycle unused bitmaps
            if (bitmap != null) 
            {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it ... the picture selected by the user is now inside **R.id.drawing**

Comment: I'm getiing an error: "void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult"

Comment: @PaulH how to set the image to the drawing view. as a background or do you have a imageview?

Comment: @PaulH .. can you give me the full code ? (make sure you did not place this code inside any function)

Comment: @niranjan94 I have added the complete code with your change recomendation.

Comment: @PaulH place it **outside** the function ...  see **http://pastebin.com/kRYBTXcr**

Comment: @niranjan94 I have the code that you have shown on the link, but it still comes up with the "void is an invalid type for variable onActivityResult" its also showing up as "bitmap cannot be resolved"

Comment: @niranjan94 Sorry I have the bitmap issue sorted but still struggling with onActivityResult. I'll update my code to see if I have done anything wrong.